# Hunt down all those questions that have only a single tag!

Tags: discussion, tags

> I created...
>
> Lies, you just used another query and improved it!
>
> SHUT UP! *boom* *bang* *thud*

As I said, I modified a query in the Data Explorer to find lonely tags. You know, those questions that only have a [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04) and nothing else.

Here is the modified query:

- [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04): [Link](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/156001/find-lonely-tags?TagName=12.04)
- [13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/13.04): [Link](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/156001/find-lonely-tags?TagName=13.04)
- [12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.10): [Link](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/156001/find-lonely-tags?TagName=12.10)
- [13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/13.10): [Link](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/156001/find-lonely-tags?TagName=13.10)

[Base query](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/156001/find-lonely-tags)