# When a version specific tag alone is good in a single question?

Tags: discussion, tags

Ok, I'm here so people can point me out where my logic is wrong. I'm talking about the version specific tags.

Every time I create, see, modify, processes a question or answer using the queues, looking at the front page, etc. I verify the tags. Why? Because that's the main stream for me to answer questions in all SE. For me, tags are vital, that's why I go around taking care of them so much.

Part of my process of verification of the tags includes the following rule:

> tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

So, each time I see a tag I evaluate the face value<sup>1</sup> of the tag, each time there are tags that still haven't quite fit withing all the evaluations I do over them, specifically the version specific tags [7.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/7.04), [7.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/7.10), [8.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/8.04), [8.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/8.10), [9.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/9.04), [9.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/9.10), [10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/10.04), [10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/10.10), [11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/11.04), [11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/11.10), [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04), [12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.10), [13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/13.04), [13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/13.10) and [14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/14.04). They fail one of the rules that I cannot be lax about, the ones contained in the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/create-tags) which every member should follow and enforce.

Now, and here is where someone should help me, which question I can ask that could have any of these tags as single tag that is not included in another tag?

I've racking my brains out several times looking where it should be used (in fact each time I see them) and still doesn't fit the criteria of *"tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, **are not allowed**"*. I've asked for examples of when the tag could be *alone* in the question and sadly nobody offered one that could not be refuted. So, I ask you, please, provide an example of when this tag could be alone so I can use it as reference whenever I see these tags.

---

Bonus points: if the tag doesn't exist tomorrow, what's the worse could happen?

---

<sup>1</sup> [Face Value](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/face_value#Noun): No more or less than what is stated; a literal or direct meaning or interpretation.

Comment: I agree that version tags can't stand alone but I foresee a lot of "which version are you running" comments if they are dropped which clutter AU more than the tags.

Comment: @Tim people most of the time just use the suggested tag that the system offers and some of them already have the version of Ubuntu somewhere in the question already. Try asking a few questions ;)

Comment: My questions would be off-topic, I'm always running Ubuntu +1 ;)

Comment: @Tim you naughty guy... :P

Comment: See also: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok

Comment: @Shog9 interesting, the first phrase of the accepted answer talk about abuse. I´ve seen people editing quesitons just to add the tag and also the proporcion of the tags itself is worring (about 20% has any of this tags).

Comment: The pitfall you want to watch out for, @Braiam, is where folks add one of these as the *only* tag on their question. See the discussions leading up to that one as well.

Comment: @Shog9 I think we are already in the pitfall. Most reviewers doesn't check that a question has the correct tag, which I have raised awareness several times ([first paragraph](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7733/169736)) and members had even said that they "don't care" whenever a question is correctly tagged. I'm going to run some checks in the SEDE later on and will see exactly how many users actually correct a tag when they see them wrong.

Comment: Don't *speculate*, @Braiam - [find and fix](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/163930/questions-with-a-single-tag?TagName=13.10)

Comment: @Shog9 I didn't http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/171157/search-edit-summary-and-group-them?CommentText=tag ;)

Comment: Good job then! We might want to discuss options for identifying these questions more readily then.

Comment: @Shog9 so, where we start? Teaching users how to tag or correct incorrectly tagged questions, fixing everything at the same time? How could we coordinate efforts for a better tagging?

Comment: The query I linked will pull up a handy list of single-version-tag questions - why not kick off a little group event & see if you can get folks involved retagging them?

Comment: @Shog9 I did [try](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7909/169736) but it didn't got traction, maybe a featured could help it *wink wink*

Comment: You left out actual instructions for what to *do* with them, @Braiam. Y'know, something like, "add additional tags to better describe the context for the question beyond *just* the version of the OS". Take a page from Oli's book.

Comment: @Shog9 I presume that's the basic, no? And [I already did](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7510/169736) (before the last paragraph). I'm not saying that someone book should be followed or not, but the situation *merits some kind of action*. I certainly won't check over [46k posts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/7.04+or+7.10+or+8.04+or+8.10+or+9.04+or+9.10+or+10.04+or+10.10+or+11.04+or+11.10+or+12.04+or+12.10+or+13.04+or+13.10+or+14.04) tags just for the sake of it, and would rather start over/total re-engineering which is more reasonable weighting in cost/benefits following a very strict

Comment: ruleset. That's my take. A family of tags taking up to 1/3 of  all questions should ring some alarms.

Comment: Look, I'm just saying: if you're gonna raise a call to action and then shrug & say "no one cared" - you'd best make sure you've actually specified what action you were hoping to call folks to. Many hands make light work, but without a clear task to do and sense of progress doing it, they'll find something else. As for *this* proposal, I think it's pretty clearly dead in the water - folks find version tags more useful here than they find the lack of other tags.

Comment: @Shog9 *I gave up* trying to do something with the *current* situation. If one of the "leaders" of the communities doesn't recognize the **abuse** which I've pointed out several occasion using several points of views, proposing several solutions and all of them shut down and brushed off as "it's not a problem", what would you expect me to do next? I'm tired of being the only one worrying about the tags. [I'm remained that tags are apparently a non-useful tool](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=14854227#14854227) where the problems pointed could be alleviated improving tagging,

Comment: making efficient use of them, and **promoting them**. The problem is that you can't promote something flawed, and I see a dip in the amount of answers that I give because of this situation since I became dependent of the tags.

Comment: I think you're being myopic here, @Braiam - tags are a means to an end, not an end in themselves. But, that's a topic for another day.

Comment: @Shog9 exactly, the means to answer questions (and sorry, no, I always put that as my goal, answering questions I mean). Are they fulfilling that role? I dare to say that most of the time they doesn't, which leads me to my previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to convert your rules into guidelines. This is editorial stuff and that's really subjective. Chances are by nuking a ton of tags you might be causing a moderator to pull out hair.

I will concede that a tag that can't stand alone probably isn't the best tag. But it's not neccessarily evil and by extension, removing it might not improve the question or the site. A tag is a layer of information about a question. As long as it's relevant, and it's about the question and not the post (a meta tag) more information is always better.

I understand that somebody only picking one version tag for their question is crappy. I get your frustration there... But that doesn't mean the version tag is at fault, it means the user has tagged poorly. Want to fix it? Add more, relevant tags.

And if I had dev access I'd make it so some tags can't be used on their own. Version tags would fall into this group.

Comment: I was, since small, grilled that when something said "this is not allowed" there must be a good reason why it isn't, and more if I understand the reason behind it. I am sure that's what the rules are for, to be followed.

Comment: Nobody is saying "this is not allowed" though. **Version tags aren't against the rules** or even against what tags are designed to do, it's just that on their own, they're not *great* tags. I've no problem with wanting to *add* other tags to questions that only have version tags; I care if your editing means trying to purge them from the system completely.

Comment: You are not understanding... "tags that can't be alone are against the rules". You reckon that version tags alone doesn't tell me anything about how can I solve the question nor if it's interesting to me at all, hence they are not allowed. I will say the same against the toshiba tag or any other. I want they removed not because I want them removed but because they are *abused* and *overused* in non-version agnostic questions. I'm using the help center (rules) to help as only weapon. I know you guys love that tag, but I don't see why they are keep apart of the fact that you want them here.

Comment: Where are you pulling that rule from? If it's "If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag", as I've already explained a few times, these *can* be used on their own (it's just *better* if they're not) and you need to focus on the "probably" because the Death of Meta Tags post does enumerate that "meta tags" are things that describe the post and not its content (like beginner, best-practices). A version tag is describing part of the problem.