# Old question with old answer. How can I request an update on the topic?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I find an old question on Ask Ubuntu with an old answer. Updates in software tend to change the way things are done, and I can't help but wonder if there is a newer solution to the same problem.

I am tempted to post a new question, but that would surely raise a duplicate alert.

What can I do to request an updated answer that's up to date to recent software updates?

Answer (score 18):

What some people do is they just leave a comment on an apparently good answer

> Is your answer stll valid in 14.04?

Whenever I get such a message I will re-evaluate my answer to see if there was something I could improve, or whether the procedures still hold true. Quite often there is something to be done, if it was only a newer screenshot. If all was good I then drop a reply like

@`<user>`: Yes, it still works like that.

This approach always makes me feel better than an unexplained or explained downvote on an excavated now dated answer I gave years ago. Howver it will only work for answers given by people who are still around.

Answer (score 11):

There is a Bounty reason devoted to this:

[image]

Comment: What if I don't have rep points to spare? Usually I am not even sure whether the answer is out-of-date or not.

Comment: Ask a user in chat? I have seen some of the more rep endowed spare some for a good reason.

Comment: and you can always drop a comment on the question/answer that it might not work as expected in a certain version

Answer (score -3):

I think you should post a new question, as this is version specific. It's a different version of the software, therefore the question is not fundamentally the same. Make sure to specify that it is a different version though!

Also, if the other post is old enough, the duplicate is usually ignored because this is technology: things change all the time.

If it is marked as dupe, pop into chat or Meta and make your case why it should be opened again. We'll (usually) listen.

Comment: If Braiam and Oli get here, I'll get the popcorn out: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8873/158442

Comment: @muru How about now? Yes?

Comment: I'm not getting into this debate, I just wanted to point out an older instance of it. :)