# OS Release in Questions

Tags: feature-request

Given the number of questions asked which do not include the OS release, thus requiring asking the OP to (at best) amend their question or (not ideal) add the info in a comment, it is possible that the question s/w can be adapted to require a release number before allowing the question to be posted?

Comment: This is old but still seems relevant, I didn't flag as a duplicate because it seems it might be a good idea to bring it up again https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2212/can-we-make-version-tags-a-must-for-every-question Also, there is some debate if the tags should be added at all on questions that are version agnostic https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14075/what-does-version-specific-mean-in-only-use-version-tag-if-the-question-is-ve https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1514/when-should-we-use-the-versions-tags/1521#1521

Answer (score 2):

I'm still against the idea for the same reasons for the answers linked in Mark's comments.

- [When should we use the versions tags?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1514/when-should-we-use-the-versions-tags/1521#1521)
- [What does "version-specific" mean in "Only use version tag if the question is version-specific"?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14075/what-does-version-specific-mean-in-only-use-version-tag-if-the-question-is-ve)
- [Can we make version tags a must for every question?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2212/can-we-make-version-tags-a-must-for-every-question)

Personally, I don't find it frequent enough to have it mandatory. I've removed version information from posts more than I have seen them being needed or requested.

My main concern is Jeff's answer. We will have an abundance of posts that will have only a version tag. That would end up making it useless.