# Best way to update question and answer for multiple KDE versions

Tags: discussion

Some time ago I self-answered a question about Emacs window behavior with KDE Plasma 4: [How to remove gap around maximized Emacs frame on KDE4](https://askubuntu.com/q/787694/257430)

I recently switched to KDE 5.5 and realized that the problem persists and the answer still works, so the problem is not limited to KDE 4. I would like to update my question and answer, but am not sure about the best way to do it:

1. Change name and tags of the question. Add kde5 tag.
2. Change name and tags of the question. Remove all version-specific KDE tags.
3. Keep the question as is. Add "This also works for KDE5" to the answer.

I personally lean towards towards solution 1 since it most accurately represents what I know (it works for KDE4 and KDE5). However, solution 2 might be easier to maintain.

Any thoughts on that? Is there a standard procedure for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of why many [questions shouldn't be tagged with version information](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8875/158442). Most questions aren't version specific. Mentioning version info in the question is fine and useful, but tagging rarely is.

We have a number of questions that have grown beyond the version they were posted for. In such cases, if the answers differ by version, we state the versions an answer works for in that answer.

I'm going to go ahead and remove the mentions of "KDE4" from that question and keep it a generalised  "KDE". In case KDE6 has a different answer, whoever posts it can state that it is for KDE6 in the answer.

I have also added the [window-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window-management) and [kwin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kwin) tags since this is a window management issue and kwin is KDE's usual window manager.